# Silverstripe: Instagram Widget - Undefined property: stdClass::$data

Tags: php, json, api, instagram, silverstripe

Getting this error from an instagram widget:

```
[Notice] Undefined property: stdClass::$data 
GET /

Line 146 in /massi/widget_imagegallery/ImageGalleryWidget.php
```

Here is the Widget.php code. Line 146 is "foreach ($json->data ....":

```
$numberOfImages = $this->MaxImageCount;
            if (!is_numeric($numberOfImages) || $numberOfImages === 0) {
                $numberOfImages = 500;
            }

            $service = new RestfulService(sprintf('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%s/media/recent/?access_token=%s&count=%d', $this->InstagramUserID, $this->InstagramAccessToken, $numberOfImages));
            $xml = $service->request()->getBody();
            $json = json_decode($xml);

            $arrayList = arrayList::create();

            $current = 1;
            if ($json) {
                $index = 0;
                foreach ($json->data as $listItem) {
                    if ($current <= $numberOfImages) {

                        $data = array(
                            'ImageNormal'      => $listItem->images->standard_resolution->url,
                            'Shape'            => $this->ImageShape( $counter ),
                            'ExtraClasses'     => $this->ImageExtraClasses( $counter ),
                            'ImageGalleryType' => $this->ImageGalleryType,
                            'DataSource' => $this->DataSource,
                            'Pos'              => $index,
                            'Title'            => $listItem->caption->text
                        );


                        $imageGalleryItemsList->push($data);

                    }
                    $counter ++;
                    $index ++;
                }
            }
```

I've got the correct access token and user ID in the settings. It appears that the code isn't getting anything back from Instagram when it requests the data?

Comment: I am not familiar with this API, but does it return XML or JSON? If it returns XML, it might explain the error as your treat it as JSON. If it's JSON, do not call it `$xml`. To know what `$json` contains, you can use `Debug::dump($json)`. It appears it does not have the property `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instagram API returns a json object with all the media stored under the data property:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self

Which explains the `foreach ($json->data as $listItem)`.

So if the `data` property doesn't exist that could mean either the api returned an error or there is no `data`.

Dump the json data and you'll know what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that. Turns out that nothing was being retrieved from Instagram. After further investigation, the problem was that the Access Code was incorrect. I generated a new one through OAuth, and updated the settings.

Also, because my app was still in Sandbox mode, it was trying to retrieve more than 20 images. Set max images to 10 and updated the access code and it's now working fine.